# VB.NET - Programatically close the chart data object

Tags: vb.net, automation, powerpoint

My program is automating PowerPoint to loop through a series of chart parameters and create a new chart per parameter set. So far it works well for the first chart - however, it throws an error when attempting to create a second chart because the chart data grid is already open, and I can't find a method to properly close or dispose of the data grid after generating the graph.

Abridged code:

```
Imports Powerpoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Private Sub generatePowerPoint(Qnum As String)
Try
   'Create PowerPoint object and assign a presentation / slide to it
        Dim oApp As Powerpoint.Application
        Dim oPres As Powerpoint.Presentation
        Dim oSlide As Powerpoint.Slide

        oApp = New Powerpoint.Application()
        oApp.Visible = True
        oApp.WindowState = Powerpoint.PpWindowState.ppWindowMinimized

        oPres = oApp.Presentations.Add

        'Prepare to generate charts based on parameters in a listbox
        Dim slideCount = lbQuestions.Items.Count


        For slideN = 1 To slideCount
         'Add a blank slide per graph request   
         oSlide = oPres.Slides.Add(slideN, Powerpoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank)

            'Create a new shape object for each slide
            Dim chartShape(slideCount) As Powerpoint.Shape

            ' What's causing the error: assign a chart object to the next shape object.
            ' This works for the first slide, but then throws an error that the PowerPoint 
            'Chart Data Grid is still open, preventing it from creating a new chart.

            chartShape(slideN - 1) = oSlide.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, ChartFind(chartType), 50, 50, 775, 410)
            Dim cData = chartShape(slideN - 1).Chart.ChartData 'Activate to refresh

            Dim workbook = cData.Workbook
            workbook.Application.Visible = False

            Dim datasheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)

            Dim colNumber As Integer = 2
            Dim firstRowNumber As Integer = 2

            datasheet.rows.clear()
            datasheet.columns.clear()

            For r = categoryNames.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1 

                datasheet.Cells(r + firstRowNumber, 1) = categoryNames(r)

            Next

      ... Code to assign data and format the chart object ...

           'Refresh the range accepted by the chart object
            chartShape(slideN-1).Chart.Refresh
     'Loop again
       Next
```

I've spent some time going through the PowerPoint Interop docs and the PowerPoint Chart Object Model docs on msdn (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff760412(v=office.14), https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/chartdata-object-powerpoint), and it seems that there's while there's a method to call the Chart Data Grid (chartdata.activate()) , there isn't a method to close the Chart Data Grid.

The exact error message thrown is "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xBFFF64AA): The chart data grid is already open in 'Presentation 1 - PowerPoint'. To edit the data for this chart, you need to close it first. at Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shapes.AddChart2( ..."

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Solved, mostly. For those who may have the same issue:

```
chartShape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.close()
```

This is an undocumented method / IntelliSense will not provide it (hence the capitalization on Close), but after opening a chart object and editing the data, make sure you finish the code block with this before attempting to create a new chart object.

Now, this doesn't work if the open workbook isn't the one you opened (so for example, I can't test if there is a workbook opened by the user, and if so, close it). I'm resolving this issue by encapsulating the AddChart2 method in a Try Catch method, and if an error is thrown I let the user know to close the window and exit the subroutine so the program doesn't crash.